# Saving file asynchronously on Django

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

I have a Django storage (boto3) that saves my files at some point during request/response cycle.
I need to speed up the cycle, so I decided to save the file in an async manner.

my code (storage)

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from storages.utils import clean_name
import asyncio

class FileStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    bucket_name = '####'


    async def _save(self, name, content):
        # save it in async mode
        await asyncio.create_task(sync_to_async(super()._save)(name, content))
        # return super()._save(name, content)
        return clean_name(name)
```

But I am getting this error now:

```
  File "...lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 58, in save
    validate_file_name(name, allow_relative_path=True)
  File "....lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/utils.py", line 9, in validate_file_name
    if os.path.basename(name) in {"", ".", ".."}:
  File "...lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 142, in basename
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not coroutine
```

Comment: Aside from the serious doubts I have about the approach (`sync_to_async`) here in principle, that error message seems pretty clear to me: You can't just stick a coroutine function where the rest of the code expects a normal function. Since neither the code you provided nor the error traceback is complete (see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), I can only guess, but it seems like the output of `_save` should be a file path of some sort. Whatever function is calling `_save` would now have to `await` it as well before it can use the output.